# FCM onNotification ionic not doing anything

Tags: c#, angular, ionic4, cordova-plugin-fcm

I'm using Ionic 4 and currently my app does subscribe to a topic but the onNotification.subcribe does not fire at all

I'm using postman to test and from what I can see I need to add click_action to my json payload under notifications to get onNotification to fire but when I do this I get an error 
This is the error FCM returns in postman when I add click_action

I am testing on Android and not on iOS

```
"code": 400,
"message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"click_action\" at 'message.notification': Cannot find field.",
"status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
```

this is how my json payload looks like

```
{
"message":{
    "data":{
        "route":"dashboard"
    },
    "topic":"6616",
    "notification":{
        "title":"user id ",
        "body":"body test 2",
        "click_action":"FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY"
    }
}
```

any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I presume you are testing with iOS?

Comment: No I'm testing on Android

Answer (score 0):

So for Android / Google ecosystem, the payload is different from what APN/iOS requires different treatment.

click_action is only relevant for Google/Android

See example of cross-platform notification message:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#example-notification-message-with-platform-specific-delivery-options

See more here to properly configure the notification object and payloads per platform: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support

Comment: I am currently only testing on Android. most working examples I come across says to use click_action like this "click_action":"FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY", but fcm api returns INVALID_ARGUMENT error. I want to know why its giving me this error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a desciption how to work with google fcm notification within [ionic](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/guides/push-notifications-firebase/).

you need to start a firebase-project with notification service an download the google-services.json

Capacitor has in-built Push notification capability. Import Push in your app/page with this

**install:**

```
ionic start capApp blank
ionic integrations enable capacitor

npx cap init
? App name: CapApp
? App Package ID: com.mydomain.myappname

ionic build

npx cap add android
```

**Code:**

```
imports in home.page.ts

import {
  Plugins,
  PushNotification,
  PushNotificationToken,
  PushNotificationActionPerformed } from '@capacitor/core';

const { PushNotifications } = Plugins;

export class HomePage implements OnInit {

ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Initializing HomePage');

    // Register with Apple / Google to receive push via APNS/FCM
    PushNotifications.register();

    // On success, we should be able to receive notifications
    PushNotifications.addListener('registration', 
      (token: PushNotificationToken) => {
        alert('Push registration success, token: ' + token.value);
      }
    );

    // Some issue with our setup and push will not work
    PushNotifications.addListener('registrationError', 
      (error: any) => {
        alert('Error on registration: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
      }
    );

    // Show us the notification payload if the app is open on our device
    PushNotifications.addListener('pushNotificationReceived', 
      (notification: PushNotification) => {
        alert('Push received: ' + JSON.stringify(notification));
      }
    );

    // Method called when tapping on a notification
    PushNotifications.addListener('pushNotificationActionPerformed', 
      (notification: PushNotificationActionPerformed) => {
        alert('Push action performed: ' + JSON.stringify(notification));
      }
    );
}
```

Another way with [ionic 4](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-get-push-notifications-working-with-ionic-4-and-firebase-ad87cc92394e/)

[ionic 4 react app using capacitor](https://enappd.com/blog/firebase-push-notification-in-ionic-react-capacitor/111/)

With Ionic cordova plugin for fcm it is not so easy to work and test, I think capacitor is a better solution!